# Conda does not create environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I am working on a shared project stored in bitbucket. I am trying to import the environment that it is used there. After I `git clone`, I have everything that I need in my PyCharm project folder. The environment is saved as a YAML file. What I do next is, I open the Anaconda Prompt and navigate to the PyCharm project folder. I try:

`conda env create -f environment.yml`

After it collects the metadata package successfully, it errors:

`Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.`

It then examines all of these conflicts but to no avail.

### Environment Information

```
(base) C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\xxxx>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\xxxx\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\xxxx\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\xxxx\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\xxxx\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.2 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

### YAML file

This is the YAML file:

```
name: whatever
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.5=py36_0
  - dlib=19.7=np111py36_0
  - freetype=2.7=vc14_2
  - pillow=4.2.1=py36_0
  - _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf=0.1.0=py36he6757f0_0
  - alabaster=0.7.10=py36hcd07829_0
  - anaconda-client=1.6.14=py36_0
  - anaconda=custom=py36h363777c_0
  - anaconda-navigator=1.8.7=py36_0
  - anaconda-project=0.8.2=py36hfad2e28_0
  - asn1crypto=0.24.0=py36_0
  - astroid=1.6.4=py36_0
  - astropy=3.0.2=py36h452e1ab_1
  - atomicwrites=1.1.5=py36_0
  - attrs=18.1.0=py36_0
  - babel=2.6.0=py36_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py36_0
  - backports=1.0=py36h81696a8_1
  - backports.shutil_get_terminal_size=1.0.0=py36h79ab834_2
  - beautifulsoup4=4.6.0=py36hd4cc5e8_1
  - bitarray=0.8.1=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - bkcharts=0.2=py36h7e685f7_0
  - blaze=0.11.3=py36h8a29ca5_0
  - bleach=2.1.3=py36_0
  - blosc=1.14.3=he51fdeb_0
  - bokeh=0.12.16=py36_0
  - boost=1.65.1=py36_4
  - boost-cpp=1.65.1=hfa6e2cd_4
  - boto=2.48.0=py36h1a776d2_1
  - boto3=1.7.24=py36_0
  - botocore=1.10.24=py36_0
  - bottleneck=1.2.1=py36hd119dfa_0
  - bzip2=1.0.6=hfa6e2cd_5
  - ca-certificates=2018.03.07=0
  - cachecontrol=0.12.4=py36_0
  - certifi=2018.4.16=py36_0
  - cffi=1.11.5=py36h945400d_0
  - chardet=3.0.4=py36h420ce6e_1
  - click=6.7=py36hec8c647_0
  - cloudpickle=0.5.3=py36_0
  - clyent=1.2.2=py36hb10d595_1
  - colorama=0.3.9=py36h029ae33_0
  - comtypes=1.1.4=py36_0
  - conda=4.5.4=py36_0
  - conda-build=3.10.7=py36_0
  - conda-env=2.6.0=h36134e3_1
  - conda-verify=2.0.0=py36h065de53_0
  - console_shortcut=0.1.1=h6bb2dd7_3
  - contextlib2=0.5.5=py36he5d52c0_0
  - cryptography=2.2.2=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - curl=7.60.0=h7602738_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py36h009560c_0
  - cython=0.28.3=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - cytoolz=0.9.0.1=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - dask=0.17.5=py36_0
  - dask-core=0.17.5=py36_0
  - datashape=0.5.4=py36h5770b85_0
  - decorator=4.3.0=py36_0
  - distlib=0.2.7=py36_0
  - distributed=1.21.8=py36_0
  - docutils=0.14=py36h6012d8f_0
  - entrypoints=0.2.3=py36hfd66bb0_2
  - et_xmlfile=1.0.1=py36h3d2d736_0
  - fastcache=1.0.2=py36hfa6e2cd_2
  - filelock=3.0.4=py36_0
  - flask=1.0.2=py36_1
  - flask-cors=3.0.4=py36_0
  - gensim=3.4.0=py36h452e1ab_0
  - get_terminal_size=1.0.0=h38e98db_0
  - gevent=1.3.2.post0=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - glob2=0.6=py36hdf76b57_0
  - greenlet=0.4.13=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - h5py=2.8.0=py36h3bdd7fb_0
  - hdf5=1.10.2=hac2f561_1
  - heapdict=1.0.0=py36_2
  - html5lib=1.0.1=py36h047fa9f_0
  - icc_rt=2017.0.4=h97af966_0
  - icu=58.2=ha66f8fd_1
  - idna=2.6=py36h148d497_1
  - imageio=2.3.0=py36_0
  - imagesize=1.0.0=py36_0
  - intel-openmp=2018.0.0=8
  - ipykernel=4.8.2=py36_0
  - ipython=6.4.0=py36_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py36h3c5d0ee_0
  - ipywidgets=7.2.1=py36_0
  - isort=4.3.4=py36_0
  - itsdangerous=0.24=py36hb6c5a24_1
  - jdcal=1.4=py36_0
  - jedi=0.12.0=py36_1
  - jinja2=2.10=py36h292fed1_0
  - jmespath=0.9.3=py36h0745840_0
  - jpeg=9b=hb83a4c4_2
  - jsonschema=2.6.0=py36h7636477_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py36_4
  - jupyter_client=5.2.3=py36_0
  - jupyter_console=5.2.0=py36h6d89b47_1
  - jupyter_core=4.4.0=py36h56e9d50_0
  - jupyterlab=0.32.1=py36_0
  - jupyterlab_launcher=0.10.5=py36_0
  - krb5=1.16=he625fcf_6
  - lazy-object-proxy=1.3.1=py36hd1c21d2_0
  - libboost=1.65.1=he51fdeb_4
  - libcurl=7.60.0=hc4dcbb0_0
  - libiconv=1.15=h1df5818_7
  - libpython=2.1=py36_0
  - libsodium=1.0.16=h9d3ae62_0
  - libssh2=1.8.0=hd619d38_4
  - libtiff=4.0.9=hb8ad9f9_1
  - libxml2=2.9.8=hadb2253_1
  - libxslt=1.1.32=hf6f1972_0
  - llvmlite=0.23.1=py36hcacf6c6_0
  - locket=0.2.0=py36hfed976d_1
  - lockfile=0.12.2=py36h0468280_0
  - lxml=4.2.1=py36heafd4d3_0
  - lzo=2.10=h6df0209_2
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - markupsafe=1.0=py36h0e26971_1
  - mccabe=0.6.1=py36hb41005a_1
  - menuinst=1.4.14=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - mistune=0.8.3=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - mkl=2018.0.2=1
  - mkl-service=1.1.2=py36h57e144c_4
  - more-itertools=4.2.0=py36_0
  - mpmath=1.0.0=py36hacc8adf_2
  - msgpack-python=0.5.6=py36he980bc4_0
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
  - multipledispatch=0.5.0=py36_0
  - navigator-updater=0.2.1=py36_0
  - nb_anacondacloud=1.4.0=py36_0
  - nb_conda=2.2.0=py36_0
  - nb_conda_kernels=2.1.0=py36_0
  - nbconvert=5.3.1=py36h8dc0fde_0
  - nbformat=4.4.0=py36h3a5bc1b_0
  - networkx=2.1=py36_0
  - nltk=3.3.0=py36_0
  - nose=1.3.7=py36h1c3779e_2
  - notebook=5.5.0=py36_0
  - numba=0.38.0=py36h830ac7b_0
  - numexpr=2.6.5=py36hcd2f87e_0
  - numpy=1.11.3=py36h4a99626_4
  - numpydoc=0.8.0=py36_0
  - odo=0.5.1=py36h7560279_0
  - olefile=0.45.1=py36_0
  - openpyxl=2.5.3=py36_0
  - openssl=1.0.2o=h8ea7d77_0
  - packaging=17.1=py36_0
  - pandas=0.23.0=py36h830ac7b_0
  - pandoc=1.19.2.1=hb2460c7_1
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py36h3ef6317_1
  - parso=0.2.1=py36_0
  - partd=0.3.8=py36hc8e763b_0
  - path.py=11.0.1=py36_0
  - pathlib2=2.3.2=py36_0
  - patsy=0.5.0=py36_0
  - pep8=1.7.1=py36_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.4=py36h9de030f_0
  - pip=10.0.1=py36_0
  - pkginfo=1.4.2=py36_1
  - pluggy=0.6.0=py36hc7daf1e_0
  - ply=3.11=py36_0
  - progress=1.3=py36hbeca8d3_0
  - prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py36h60b8f86_0
  - psutil=5.4.5=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - py=1.5.3=py36_0
  - py-boost=1.65.1=py36h6538335_4
  - pycodestyle=2.4.0=py36_0
  - pycosat=0.6.3=py36h413d8a4_0
  - pycparser=2.18=py36hd053e01_1
  - pycrypto=2.6.1=py36hfa6e2cd_8
  - pycurl=7.43.0.1=py36h74b6da3_0
  - pyflakes=2.0.0=py36_0
  - pygments=2.2.0=py36hb010967_0
  - pylint=1.9.1=py36_0
  - pyodbc=4.0.23=py36h6538335_0
  - pyopenssl=18.0.0=py36_0
  - pyparsing=2.2.0=py36h785a196_1
  - pyqt=5.6.0=py36hb5ed885_5
  - pysocks=1.6.8=py36_0
  - pytables=3.4.3=py36he6f6034_1
  - pytest=3.6.0=py36_1
  - pytest-arraydiff=0.2=py36_0
  - pytest-astropy=0.3.0=py36_0
  - pytest-doctestplus=0.1.3=py36_0
  - pytest-openfiles=0.3.0=py36_0
  - pytest-remotedata=0.2.1=py36_0
  - python=3.6.5=h0c2934d_0
  - python-dateutil=2.7.3=py36_0
  - pytz=2018.4=py36_0
  - pywavelets=0.5.2=py36hc649158_0
  - pywin32=223=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - pywinpty=0.5.3=py36_0
  - pyyaml=3.12=py36h1d1928f_1
  - pyzmq=17.0.0=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - qtawesome=0.4.4=py36h5aa48f6_0
  - qtconsole=4.3.1=py36h99a29a9_0
  - qtpy=1.4.2=py36_0
  - requests=2.18.4=py36h4371aae_1
  - rope=0.10.7=py36had63a69_0
  - ruamel_yaml=0.15.35=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - s3transfer=0.1.13=py36_0
  - scikit-image=0.13.1=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - scikit-learn=0.19.1=py36h53aea1b_0
  - scipy=1.1.0=py36h672f292_0
  - seaborn=0.8.1=py36h9b69545_0
  - send2trash=1.5.0=py36_0
  - setuptools=39.2.0=py36_0
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1=py36_2
  - singledispatch=3.4.0.3=py36h17d0c80_0
  - sip=4.18.1=py36h9c25514_2
  - six=1.11.0=py36h4db2310_1
  - smart_open=1.5.7=py36_0
  - snappy=1.1.7=h777316e_3
  - snowballstemmer=1.2.1=py36h763602f_0
  - sortedcollections=1.0.1=py36_0
  - sortedcontainers=2.0.3=py36_0
  - sphinx=1.7.5=py36_0
  - sphinxcontrib=1.0=py36hbbac3d2_1
  - sphinxcontrib-websupport=1.0.1=py36hb5e5916_1
  - spyder=3.2.8=py36_0
  - sqlalchemy=1.2.8=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - sqlite=3.23.1=h35aae40_0
  - statsmodels=0.9.0=py36h452e1ab_0
  - sympy=1.1.1=py36h96708e0_0
  - tblib=1.3.2=py36h30f5020_0
  - terminado=0.8.1=py36_1
  - testpath=0.3.1=py36h2698cfe_0
  - tk=8.6.7=hcb92d03_3
  - toolz=0.9.0=py36_0
  - tornado=5.0.2=py36_0
  - traitlets=4.3.2=py36h096827d_0
  - typing=3.6.4=py36_0
  - unicodecsv=0.14.1=py36h6450c06_0
  - urllib3=1.22=py36h276f60a_0
  - vc=14=h0510ff6_3
  - vs2015_runtime=14.0.25123=3
  - wcwidth=0.1.7=py36h3d5aa90_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py36h67c50ae_1
  - werkzeug=0.14.1=py36_0
  - wheel=0.31.1=py36_0
  - widgetsnbextension=3.2.1=py36_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.0.1=py36he67d7fd_1
  - win_unicode_console=0.5=py36hcdbd4b5_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py36h7fe50ca_0
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - wrapt=1.10.11=py36he5f5981_0
  - xlrd=1.1.0=py36h1cb58dc_1
  - xlsxwriter=1.0.5=py36_0
  - xlwings=0.11.8=py36_0
  - xlwt=1.3.0=py36h1a4751e_0
  - yaml=0.1.7=hc54c509_2
  - zeromq=4.2.5=hc6251cf_0
  - zict=0.1.3=py36h2d8e73e_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h8395fce_2
  - pip:
    - _nb_ext_conf==0.4.0=py36_1
    - bz2file==0.98=py36_0
    - libpng==1.6.30=vc14_1
    - qt==5.6.2=vc14_1
    - nbpresent==3.0.2=py36_0
    - matplotlib==2.1.1=py36_0
    - absl-py==0.1.10
    - adal==0.5.0
    - azure==2.0.0
    - azure-batch==3.0.0
    - azure-common==1.1.8
    - azure-datalake-store==0.0.18
    - azure-graphrbac==0.30.0
    - azure-keyvault==0.3.7
    - azure-mgmt==1.0.0
    - azure-mgmt-authorization==0.30.0
    - azure-mgmt-batch==4.0.0
    - azure-mgmt-batchai==0.2.0
    - azure-mgmt-cdn==0.30.3
    - azure-mgmt-cognitiveservices==1.0.0
    - azure-mgmt-compute==1.0.0
    - azure-mgmt-containerregistry==0.2.1
    - azure-mgmt-datalake-analytics==0.1.6
    - azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg==2.0.0
    - azure-mgmt-datalake-store==0.1.6
    - azure-mgmt-devtestlabs==2.0.0
    - azure-mgmt-dns==1.0.1
    - azure-mgmt-documentdb==0.1.3
    - azure-mgmt-iothub==0.2.2
    - azure-mgmt-keyvault==0.31.0
    - azure-mgmt-logic==2.1.0
    - azure-mgmt-monitor==0.2.1
    - azure-mgmt-network==1.0.0
    - azure-mgmt-nspkg==2.0.0
    - azure-mgmt-rdbms==0.1.0
    - azure-mgmt-redis==4.1.1
    - azure-mgmt-resource==1.1.0
    - azure-mgmt-scheduler==1.1.3
    - azure-mgmt-sql==0.5.3
    - azure-mgmt-storage==1.0.0
    - azure-mgmt-trafficmanager==0.30.0
    - azure-mgmt-web==0.32.0
    - azure-nspkg==2.0.0
    - azure-servicebus==0.21.1
    - azure-servicefabric==5.6.130
    - azure-servicemanagement-legacy==0.20.6
    - azure-storage==0.34.3
    - azureml==0.2.7
    - cached-property==1.3.1
    - chainer==3.3.0
    - chainerrl==0.3.0
    - cntk==2.4
    - cupy==2.3.0
    - fastrlock==0.3
    - future==0.16.0
    - graphviz==0.8.2
    - gym==0.9.7
    - isodate==0.6.0
    - keras==2.1.4
    - keyring==11.0.0
    - lightgbm==2.1.0
    - markdown==2.6.11
    - msrest==0.4.26
    - msrestazure==0.4.21
    - mxnet-cu90==1.1.0b20180213
    - oauthlib==2.0.6
    - opencv-python==3.4.0.12
    - pandas-datareader==0.6.0
    - protobuf==3.5.1
    - pydocumentdb==2.3.1
    - pydot==1.2.4
    - pyglet==1.3.1
    - pyjwt==1.5.3
    - pyspark==2.2.1
    - pywin32-ctypes==0.1.2
    - requests-file==1.4.3
    - requests-ftp==0.3.1
    - requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
    - tables==3.4.3
    - tensorflow-gpu==1.5.0
    - tensorflow-tensorboard==1.5.1
    - xgboost==0.7
```

### Conda output

And this the output of the console:

```
(base) C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\xxx>conda env create -f environment.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining pickleshare==0.7.4=py36h9de030f_0:   4%|█▌                                  | 11/258 [00:00<00:03, 72.73it/s]/Examining ca-certificates==2018.03.07=0:  16%|██████▌                                 | 42/258 [00:01<00:05, 37.11it/s]-Examining nbconvert==5.3.1=py36h8dc0fde_0:  17%|██████▍                               | 44/258 [00:01<00:05, 40.76it/s]|Examining _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf==0.1.0=py36he6757f0_0:  21%|█████▏                   | 53/258 [00:01<00:07, 26.17it/s]\Examining isort==4.3.4=py36_0:  30%|██████████████▉                                   | 77/258 [00:03<00:12, 14.69it/s]|Examining jupyter_console==5.2.0=py36h6d89b47_1:  44%|█████████████▋                 | 114/258 [00:05<00:10, 13.66it/s]\Examining rope==0.10.7=py36had63a69_0:  48%|███████████████████▋                     | 124/258 [00:06<00:10, 12.21it/s]-Examining docutils==0.14=py36h6012d8f_0:  59%|███████████████████████▏               | 153/258 [00:07<00:05, 18.83it/s]\Examining greenlet==0.4.13=py36hfa6e2cd_0:  63%|███████████████████████▏             | 162/258 [00:08<00:07, 12.61it/s]|Examining ruamel_yaml==0.15.35=py36hfa6e2cd_1:  89%|█████████████████████████████▍   | 230/258 [00:11<00:01, 18.01it/s]/Examining send2trash==1.5.0=py36_0:  96%|██████████████████████████████████████████▎ | 248/258 [00:11<00:00, 22.96it/s]/Examining conflict for _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf ipywidgets ipython jupyter_console jupyter ipykernel notebook qtconsole an
Examining conflict for mccabe pytest conda-verify ipython sortedcontainers astroid rope smart_open webencodings attrs packaging nbformat xlwings lxml imagesize backports.shutil_get_terminal_size numba typing parso backports.functools_lru_cache python pickleshare sip qtconsole jsonschema anaconda dask-core locket sympy networkx console_shortcut cryptography pandas pytest-remotedata six click wcwidth jupyter pytz snowballstemmer nltk sqlalchemy alabaster cython py requests pycrypto backports spyder fastcache dlib numexpr python-dateutil pywavelets docutils pyqt numpy unicodecsv gensim tornado sphinx s3transfer pygments scipy mkl-service babel greenlet certifi gevent cycler pywin32 pathlib2 asn1crypto pycodestyle libpython path.py get_terminal_size jupyter_client contextlib2 distlib datashape bitarray llvmlite cachecontrol pandocfilters anaconda-navigator markupsafe jmespath sphinxcontrib-websupport wheel 

...

Package boost-cpp conflicts for:
dlib==19.7=np111py36_0 -> boost==1.65.1 -> boost-cpp==1.65.1
boost-cpp==1.65.1=hfa6e2cd_4

...

Package openpyxl conflicts for:
anaconda==custom=py36h363777c_0 -> _anaconda_depends -> openpyxl
openpyxl==2.5.3=py36_0
```

Comment: Does the environment.yml come from the git repo? If so, was it created on the same OS that you’re on?